# Is Cassandra able to take advantage from huge memory (RAM)

Tags: memory, memory-management, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Lets say I have a cassandra (DSE) cluster and an application that dynamically creates keyspaces and tables (this is actually a business case we have).

It is said that Cassandra reserves 1MB of memory for each table in the memory. Keyspaces don't really take up space but if tables are added dynamically eventually the whole memory will be "reserved" for all these tables. I suppose a lot of tables have to be created, but for this question, lets assume tables are added so it "eats up" the memory. So, to solve the problem I could add more memory (RAM), or will this not help?

How will Cassandra use memory if more is added? E.g. lets assume I going to the extreme and have nodes in my cluster with 244 GB RAM (AWS i2.8xlarge example), will this help me to be able to add more tables to the cluster?

Is Cassandra able to take advantage of the added RAM?

Answer (score 2):

> an application that dynamically creates keyspaces and tables (this is actually a business case we have)

You'll run into a lot of troubles. Why ?

- because Cassandra has not been designed to add new tables
  continuously on the fly
- because **schema creation and agreement** between nodes of the cluster
  takes time and you should be absolutely sure that the table has been
  created before writing into it, so it means you need to check in your
  application that schema agreement is successful. Read this:
  http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/metadata/#schema-agreement
- because you can run into **big trouble** and **destroy your cluster** when
  scaling out and having dynamic schema creation by your application
  (**unless you stop completely this dynamic schema creation feature when scaling out, which may not be possible**). Read this for more details:
  http://www.slideshare.net/doanduyhai/cassandra-nice-use-cases-and-worst-anti-patterns-no-sqlmatters-barcelona/44

> Although it was interesting reading this does not answer my question. Assume I have the control over when the keyspaces and tables are created, getting back to the original question, is Cassandra able to take advantage of the added RAM?

Yes it will, I would advise, for huge RAM scenario, to set the JVM Heap size to something huge like 128Gb and to use G1 GC

Comment: Although it was interesting reading this does not answer my question. Assume I have the control over when the keyspaces and tables are created, getting back to the original question, is Cassandra able to take advantage of the added RAM?

Comment: Cassandra can take advantage of RAM using key cache / row cache, but realistically, the OS page cache will be used. If you have 244GB of RAM, using a reasonably sized heap and leaving the rest of the RAM for OS cache is usually going to be best. In some cases, using a very very large heap and G1 (as @doanduyahi suggested) will be good, but often times you just shift from OS/kernel caching to JVM caching, which isn't always a win.